# Append to a variable from invoke-command

Tags: powershell, scope, invoke-command

I need output of variable from `Invoke-Command`, but when printing it is showing empty, below is the sample code:

```
$ServiceName = "Service"

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {

        try {
            iisreset
            $BodyContent += "Server: <b>$server</b> IIS reset completed<br>"

        }
        catch {
            $BodyContent += "Server: <b>$server</b> is Failed to restart IIS<br>"
            $ErrorStat = 1
        }

        try {
            Stop-Service -DisplayName $using:ServiceName
            $BodyContent += "Server: <b>$server</b> is successfully Stopped $using:ServiceName<br>"
        }
        catch {
            $BodyContent += "Server: <b>$server</b> is failed to Stop $using:ServiceName<br>"
            $ErrorStat = 1
        }

        try {
            Start-Service -DisplayName $using:ServiceName
            $BodyContent += "Server: <b>$server</b> is successfully Started $using:ServiceName<br>"
        }
        catch {
            $BodyContent += "Server: <b>$server</b> is failed to Start $using:ServiceName<br>"
            $ErrorStat = 1
        }

    } -ComputerName $server -Credential $user -ErrorAction Stop
```

Here, I want to capture `$BodyContent` and `$ErrorStat`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture the Return Value of a ScriptBlock invoked with Powershell's Invoke-Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8549184/how-to-capture-the-return-value-of-a-scriptblock-invoked-with-powershells-invok)

Answer (score 1):

`Invoke-Command` returns to you what is printed to the end of the pipeline. If you want to return a variable you should `Return <variable>` like:

```
$ret = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { $var="test string"; return $var; }
```

where `$ret` contains now the value `test string`.

When you got multiple variables you want to return, then you can join them into a single variable, e.g. like this:

```
$str1 = "test"
$str2 = "123"
$combinedObjs = New-Object PSObject -Property @{1 = $str1; 2 = $str2}
```

Now you can combine it all

```
$ret = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { 
  $str1 = "test";
  $str2 = "123";
  $combinedObjs =  @{val1 = $str1; val2 = $str2};
  Return $combinedObjs;
}
```

now `$ret` contains

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
val1                           test
val2                           123
```

and you can access them by calling `$ret.val1` or `$ret.val2`

Comment: I'd say _what is printed to the screen_ is not accurate.

Comment: Updated my text. That was bad wording from my side

Comment: Perfect! I suggested an edit, but this is now overriden by yours, which is Ok. I would just remove the quote marks from the inline code blocks, as they are - syntactically - not a part of the value, but this is kind of me going to be petty ;)

Answer (score 0):

Add some output to the very end of given scriptblock, e.g.

```
    @{  BodyContent = $BodyContent
        ErrorStat   = $ErrorStat
    }
```

If you use e.g.

```
$result = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { 

    ###  original script block body here

    @{  BodyContent = $BodyContent
        ErrorStat   = $ErrorStat
    }
}  -ComputerName $server -Credential $user -ErrorAction Stop
```

then you can check

```
$result.BodyContent
$result.ErrorStat
```