# How to keep a PowerShell remote session open for another follow-up Invoke-Command?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I need to check the exit code of a script block run in a remote session (started with New-PSSession) and initiated with Invoke-Command. The implementation I would prefer to use is featured [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75549824/12530550)

Here is the code snippet:

```
$RemoteSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName ... -Credential $cred 
$s = "something"
$parameters = ($parameters + $s)
$ScriptBlock = {
    function PrintObjectDetails ()
    {
        $object = [PSCustomObject]@{
            prop1 = "value1"
            prop2 = "value2"
        }
        Write-Output $object
    }

    PrintObjectDetails

    Write-Host $args[-1]

    exit 1
}
Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession -ArgumentList $parameters -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock
Invoke-Command -Session $RemoteSession -ScriptBlock { $LASTEXITCODE } -OutVariable exitCodeArray > $null
$exitCode = $exitCodeArray[0]
```

Note: I keep the object print function to just give context for the expected output sequence

The issue is I get 2 errors associated with the session not being open anymore for the second Invoke-Command:

```
Invoke-Command : Because the session state for session <id, computerName> is not equal to Open, you cannot run a command in the session.  The session state is Closing.
 
Invoke-Command : No valid sessions were specified.  Ensure you provide valid sessions that are in the Opened state and are available to run commands.
```

Why does the session close after one Invoke-Command?

How can I avoid closing it or getting $LASTEXITCODE from that run (without disrupting the output sequence)?

Comment: Try removing the "exit 1".  Exit 0 is the return code with no errors.

Comment: @jdweng The idea is to get the error code if there is one stored in the $LASTEXITCODE but the issue is still that I cannot run the second "Invoke-Command" due to errors mentioned in the question

Comment: That is why I suggested to remove the exit code.

Comment: @jdweng Yes, if the exit command does not happen, the second invoke-command seems to work. But what to do in case it happens?

Comment: Only add exit coded when there is an error.  The error should show up on the $LastExitCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Replace `exit 1` with `$LASTEXITCODE = 1` to prevent your remote session from closing after the first `Invoke-Command` call.

---

###### Background information:

- If you use `exit` in the *global* scope of a session, the session exits *as a whole*.
- Thus, your `exit 1` exits the session and thereby invariably closes the remote session stored in `$RemoteSession`.

  - Subsequent attempts to use the closed session with [`Invoke-Command`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Invoke-Command) then trigger the error you saw.
- By contrast, `exit` calls from *inside a script* exit that script only and, if an exit code was specified (using a numeric argument, e.g., `exit 1`), that exit code is recorded in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode)
- Similarly, the exit code of the most recently executed *child process* (external-program call) is recorded in `$LASTEXTICODE`.

Even though it's generally not a good idea, you *can* set `$LASTEXTICODE` directly, as shown at the top, if you really need to determine the exit code *manually* (as opposed to letting the last script / external-program call set it).